# How do I change screen resolution automatically when computer starts up?

Tags: 11.10, xrandr

I am using following command to change my screen resolution:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

Now, which file do I need to edit so it will modify my screen resolution when I start up my Ubuntu PC?

NOTE: editing `.xprofile` isn't ideal since it's only per-user, not system-wide, and GDM/KDM doesn't existed on a vanilla 11.10 install, nor does `xorg.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution :

> There are several ways to make xrandr customizations permanent from
>   session to session: a) .xprofile, b) kdm/gdm, c) xorg.conf.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a GUI frontend to Xrandr, for example [ARandR](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/).

ARandR is designed to provide a simple visual front end for XRandR. Relative monitor positions are shown graphically and can be changed in a drag-and-drop way.

[image]

To install it in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Now your configuration will be stored and loaded within the startup